# Is that possible to create APEX application which access two databases simultaneously?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to extend an existing Apex app: connection to another database is required. Would it be possible?
Or at least start Apex on one database and connect to another.

This is for Oracle 12c and Apex 5.2

Comment: Your best bet here is to access the second DB via a database link from the first one. APEX is pretty tightly tied to a single database.

Comment: or use webservices to access the second db data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database link is the best option if you want to access directly to the other database using queries, but if you want to get the information in JSON from one or two tables you can use ORDS to public a web service.